# python selenium, slow xpath 'all elements'. add timeout

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to get all the elements on a page and iterate through them to search each element.

currently I am using, `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@*]')`

However, there can be a delay in completing **the line of code above** on larger pages. Is there a way to retrieve the results in increments of 100 elements? Or at least add a timeout?

Terminating `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@*]')` inside a multithread is the only why I currently think I can solve this.

I need to find all elements on a page that contain certain strings. For example. `elem.get_attribute('outerHTML').find('type="submit"') != -1` … and so on and so forth … I also need their proximity to each other to compare index positions

Thanks!

Comment: Constructing a _xpath_ for all elements doesn't looks to be a valid _usecase_. An ideal _usecase_ should be related to a specific/definite element. Update the question with what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to find all elements on a page that contain certain strings. For example. `elem.get_attribute('outerHTML').find('type="submit"') != -1` … and so on and so forth … I also need their proximity to each other to compare index positions.

Comment: This information needs to be updated within the main question to help the contributors help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Globalz          ###### globals import is an empty .py file
import threading
import time
import ctypes


def find_xpath():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    Globalz.curr_value = 'DONE!'

    ### this is where the xpath retrieval goes (ABOVE loop is for example purposes only)



def stopwatch(info):
    curr_time = 0
    failed = False
    Globalz.curr_value = ''
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=info['function'])
    thread1.start()
    while thread1.is_alive() is True:
        if curr_time >= info['timeout']: failed = True; ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(ctypes.c_long(thread1.ident), ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))
        curr_time += 1; time.sleep(1)
    if failed is True: return info['failed_returns']
    if failed is False: return Globalz.curr_value


betty = stopwatch({'function': find_xpath, 'timeout': 10, 'failed_returns': 'failed'})
print(betty)
```

If anyone is interested here is a solution. I've created a wrapper called stopwatch()